# Heroku push. How not change one subdirectory

Tags: git, heroku

i have an heroku app and it writes some data to files while worked on production. But when i do some changes  in code on local machine and then push them to remote all files from this directory are totally deleted. 
There is some hack how to push all code changes to heroku without this directory with files?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a particular directory from getting pushed to heroku, simply add that directory to your .gitignore file.

However, I think you might have a more fundamental design problem.
You mention that your app writes data to files on the local file system in production. That is almost definitely something you DON'T want to do!!
Note that the local file system of your Heroku dynos CANNOT be used for persisting data. Every time your [Heroku dyno restarts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) for whatever reason (and that happens at least once every 24 hours or so, whether you want it to or not), ALL of the data that your production app wrote to the local file system will be lost.

Bottom line: To persist data from your production app, you need to use some sort of [stateful backing service](https://12factor.net/backing-services), such as e.g. [Heroku Redis](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!